# C++ and cast operators

Tags: c++, casting, polymorphism, static-cast

I have a question about c++ cast operators.

Suppose you have a class `Message` and several subclasses: `Message1` `Message 2` etc.

Suppose you have a class `Event` and also different subclasses of Event: `Event 1` `Event 2`

In both cases I can distinguish the type of the subclass from an `ID` (such as field)

```
class Message {
....
int MessageID;
}

class Message1 : public Message {
//other fields;
}

class Message2 : public Message {
//other fields;
}

class Event {
int eventID;
}

class Event1 {
Message theMessage;

Message getMessage();
}

class Event2 {
Message theMessage;
}
```

I insert instances Event1 or Event2  into a `vector<Event>`
in this case, when I extract an Event by the carrier, though I'm sure you have an instance of Event1, it is correct to use the `static_cast`? For example:

```
    Event theEvent = myVector.at(i);
    Event1 *e1 = static_cast<Event1*>(&theEvent);
    if(e1->getID() == xxx) {
    Message2 *m2 = static_cast<Message2*>(&e1->getMessage());
    }
```

I have a problem: after the last cast, I do not see instance information as Message2 (always only those of its parent class Message)
In this case, is necessary to use dynamic_cast?

Comment: If the vector only ever contains objects of type `Event1` make it a container of `Event1` objects. Otherwise use virtual functions or `dynamic_cast`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`e1->getMessage()` returns an object of type Message, not a pointer. So your data will be sliced. Additionally you cast a pointer to a temporary here:

```
Message2 *m2 = static_cast<Message2*>(&e1->getMessage());
```

You can do this if you return a pointer.

```
Message * getMessage() { return &theMessage; }
```

`static_cast` is the correct way of casting base pointers to derived pointers **without any runtime checks.** The "safer" way of doing this is to use dynamic_cast operator of course, since it will perform a runtime-check upon casting a derived to a base pointer or reference. (I guess I'm going to be stoned to death here if I tell you to stick to `static_cast` to avoid those checks if you got your own that is fail-proof. ;))

The best way (in my opinion) would be a proper virtual interface design in the base classes. You could avoid casting from base to derived this way.

Additionally you slice all your `Event`s if you use a `vector<Event>`. You can only use `vector<Event*>` to have your collection of derived objects since a Base pointer may point to derived objects but Base objects cannot hold Derived Data. (All derived `Event`s in your vector will miss `theMessage` and only have the data contained in `Event`.)

Comment: Poppycock! `dynamic_cast` is the correct way to downcast polymorphic types. Using `static_cast` in this case risks undefined behavior.

Comment: That depends on the way you determine your object type. If you have performed a reliable runtime check, why would you want the compiler to include any more runtime checks? Your own check may fail or be buggy so you're right it is safer to go with dynamic_cast but performance versus safety is a common consideration for me (at least when programming for HPC applications).

Comment: maybe this could be the solution? // container of base class pointers vector<Animal*> barn; // dynamically allocate an Animal instance and add it to the container barn.push_back( new Dog() ); but I can't use the dynamic memory..so the 'new' how can I achieve this?

Comment: How come you can't use new? Does this include that you do not have access to allocators as well?

Answer (score 3):

Typically, when you have derived classes, you should be using virtual functions.

In your example, perhaps the "content" in the message could be got through a virtual function.

This cast:

```
    Event1 *e1 = static_cast<Event1*>(&theEvent);
```

will not work. `theEvent` is smaller than `Event1` by a `Message` - which means that whatever message you get out of it will be "random garbage", because you only had an `Event` in the first place.

If you want to store "any type of event" in your events array, then you need to store pointers to the `Event` type, or you will definitely suffer from the slicing problem you have above.

Comment: how do you think I can solve my problem? Can you suggest a practical solution or an example to help me understand?

Comment: Since you haven't really described what is in the different types of messages - or how they are used by the calling code, it's hard to be specific.

Comment: each subclass of message has a few more fields in anything else. The parent class has some fields common to all subclasses

Comment: Yes, my point is rather about the overall picture of what you are trying to achieve with those fields, and thus understanding how to suggest a solution. The type and  number of fields as such is probably somewhat irrelevant, but how you use them and what you do to them is not.

Comment: maybe this could be the solution?
// container of base class pointers
    vector<Animal*> barn;

    // dynamically allocate an Animal instance and add it to the container
    barn.push_back( new Dog() );

but I can't use the dynamic memory..so the 'new' how can I achieve this?

Comment: Well, that is certainly PART of the problem - you need to store a pointer to things [preferably a `unique_ptr<Animal>`, so you don't have to remember to delete it later].

Answer (score 1):

Your idea, as presented is completely hopeless. You store all base classes by value in structures and the vector. That means they will be exactly that base class type, never any of your derived ones. Thus casting will not help you a bit.

You have to read up on how to store *polymorphic* objects in collections or structures. (basicly through some kind of pointers, arrangling ownership issues correctly).

After you resolved the storage issue, you can come back for the casting one -- that will be easy in comparison.

Comment: how do you think I can solve my problem? Can you suggest a practical solution or an example to help me understand?